# I want to divide by the integer type and round off the existing decimal point

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, int, laravel-5.8

I want to divide by the integer type and truncate after the decimal point.
DB column is integer

Below is the code

```
public static function time($time)
{
    $h = $time/60;
    floor($h);
    $m = $time%60;
    return $h . ':' . $m; 
}
```

When $ h is seen with dd, it comes out like this

```
1.1666666666667
```

How can I truncate after the decimal point?

Comment: `$h = floor($h)`

Comment: @catcon How easy it was :)))
I want you to write in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `floor($h)` into variable.

try

```
public static function time($time)
{
    $h = $time/60;
    $h = floor($h);
    $m = $time%60;
    return $h . ':' . $m; 
}
```

or to make it simple

```
public static function time($time)
{
    $h = floor($time/60);
    $m = $time%60;
    return $h . ':' . $m; 
}
```